# Game over pop-up like Flappy Bird

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can I make a game over pop-up like Flappy Bird in cocos2d-iphone 3?

[image]

I tried to add a new Scene, but it adds a new screen on the game, I just want a rectangle with some buttons inside it. I also search how to add multiple scene, but didn't find an example doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new Layer and put there a Menu object with the buttons you need. Make the layer visible when the game is over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the engine you're talking about, but can't you just add the 'game over' image as an object with transparent backgrounds, the places where they need to be transparent?